# Trying to determine if file has been uuencoded

Tags: python, uuencode, uudecode

I am trying to process a large collection of txt files which themselves are containers for the actual files that I am wanting to process.  The txt files have sgml tags that set boundaries for the individual files I am processing.  Sometimes, the contained files are binary that have been uuencoded.  I have solved the problem of decoding the uuencoded files but as I was mulling over my solution I have determined that it is not general enough.  That is,  I have been using

```
if '\nbegin 644 ' in document['document']
```

to test if the file is uuencoded.  I did some searching and have a vague understanding of what the 644 means (file permissions) and have then found other examples of uuencoded files that might have

```
if '\nbegin 642 ' in document['document']
```

or even some other alternates.  Thus, my problem is how do I make sure that I capture/identify all of the subcontainers that have uuencoded files.

One solution is to test every subcontainer:

```
uudecode=codecs.getdecoder("uu")

for document in documents:
    try:
        decoded_document,m=uudecode(document)
    except ValueError:
         decoded_document=''
    if len(decoded_document)==0
        more stuff
```

This is not horrible, cpu-cycles are cheap but I am going to be handling some 8 million documents.

Thus, is there a more robust way to recognize whether or not a particular string is the result of uuencoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding#Encoded_format) that every uuencoded file begins with this line

```
begin <perm> <name>
```

So probably a line matching the regexp `^begin [0-7]{3} (.*)$` denotes the beginning reliably enough.

Comment: I appreciate this thought.  I am concerned that I am not getting much though as opposed to trying to decode the file as I have to run the regexp.

Comment: A compiled regexp matches (or fails) very quickly. Maybe uudecode fails as fast and already includes this very step. The only way to determine is to actually try it on 2-3 thousand files and measure which is faster.

Comment: Note that the file doesn't have to begin with 'begin' - most modern uudecodes will ignore anything up to the first begin - this was probably so you could pipe mail straight into it and not have to filter out headers.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

(1) On Unix-based systems, you can robustly use the `file` command.

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file

```
$ file foo
foo: uuencoded or xxencoded text
```

(2) I also found the following (untested) Python code that looks like it will do what you want (at http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1304548.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import magic
import sys
filename=sys.argv[1]
ms = magic.open(magic.MAGIC_NONE)
ms.load()
ftype = ms.file(filename)
print ftype
ms.close()
```

Comment: Except for files with content before the 'begin' - which most uudecoders will skip. 'file' will probably report these as Ascii Text. Never mind you being on Windows, get Cygwin and then you can have all the Unix goodies.